# Semantic Zoom Catastrophic failure on empty group

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using the SemanticZoom control with a grid view and collection view source. All is working fine until I attempt to select ('jump to') an empty group - this causes an unhandled Catastrophic failure.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/winappswithcsharp/thread/6535656e-3293-4e0d-93b5-453864b95601

Does anybody know if there is a way to fix this - I want to 'allow' an empty group if I can.

Thanks

Comment: Incase anyone stumbles across this - it is not clear whether this is a bug or feature but the issue can be resolved by adding empty templates to the group. This is closely linked to another issue/feature that this question helps with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830101/xaml-grouped-gridview-semantic-zoom-not-displaying-all-children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I ran into this issue and fixed it. I know this is quite an old thread, but I'll answer it in case someone else runs into this. Here's how I did it.

The issue seems to be that the group set as the `DestinationItem` needs to have items in it. In the case that this group is empty, this poses a problem. The problem does *not* occur when the group is *in between other filled groups*, because it has a length of 0 and therefore is untargetable. When it is at the end (or possibly the beginning, haven't tried that), this poses an issue because the `GridView`/`ListView` *targets the last one in the list when the mouse is past the end of the view*.

So, how to solve it:

You need to add an event handler for `OnViewChangeStarted`. In this handler, you will have access to the `SemanticZoomViewChangedEventArgs`.

The first thing you need to do is find out if the Group being `targetted` is empty. I am using a custom `Group` class here, but have cast it to `IEnumerable`, just because I only need to know how many items are in it. `Linq` allows me to find the count of the `IEnumerable`.

```
using System.Linq;

private void Zoom_OnViewChangeStarted(object sender, SemanticZoomViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var group = e.DestinationItem.Item as IEnumerable;
    if (group != null && group.Count() == 0)
    {
        e.DestinationItem.Item = MyViewModel.Groups.Last(itemGroup => itemGroup.Count() > 0);
    }
}
```

As you'll note, the next step is to set the `DestinationItem.Item` to the `Last` group that has items in it. You may also want to handle the First group that has items in it, but that's quite easy to do as well. In place of `MyViewModel`, insert your `ViewModel`. In place of `Groups`, insert your collection property.

I hope this helps and happy coding!